# OpenERP / Odoo - How to use XML RPC with c# and How to generate WSDL

Tags: wsdl, xml-rpc, odoo

I want to use Odoo XML RPC with c# application.

In Odoo documentation I have read Login method and Create method

```
final XmlRpcClientConfigImpl common_config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
common_config.setServerURL(
new URL(String.format("%s/xmlrpc/2/common", url)));
client.execute(common_config, "version", emptyList());
```

So where can I find WSDL files for all Odoo methods or how to generate WSDL files?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes I'm also looking for the same, documentation is not proper

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this library, this is library to connect to odoo CRUD operation in C#
https://openerpnet.codeplex.com/documentation